# Line wrapping of l3msg messages

Tags: expl3, warnings

The L3 programming layer (aka `expl3`) has the `l3msg` package to provide infrastructure for all sorts of messages, warnings, errors etc. It has, however, a particular style of line-wrapping of the messages, which make for well visible messages in the console, log, etc., but which does pose some challenges for machine reading of the log.

Consider the following document to illustrate the behavior:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { long-package-name } { warning-message }
  {
    Warning~'#1'~for~label~'#2'~\msg_line_context:.~
    Some~more~interesting~information~to~emphasize~the~wrapping.
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \packagewarning { m m }
  { \msg_warning:nnnn { long-package-name } { warning-message } {#1} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Hello!

\packagewarning{x}{y}

\packagewarning{lorem}{ipsum}

\end{document}
```

This outputs the following in the console (extract):

```
Package long-package-name Warning: Warning 'x' for label 'y' on line 17. Some
(long-package-name)                more interesting information to emphasize
(long-package-name)                the wrapping.


Package long-package-name Warning: Warning 'lorem' for label 'ipsum' on line
(long-package-name)                19. Some more interesting information to
(long-package-name)                emphasize the wrapping.
```

So the line wrapping style builds a "header" with `Package <module> Warning:` , which takes a number of columns, and the actual message is wrapped in the columns that remain, which may be a short number (shorter as the package name gets longer).

It does make for a clear and easy reading of a person looking at the console output. But a number of editors parse the console output by different methods to assist users in the task. For example, for the above document, AUCTeX is able to identify the line of the first message and take me directly to the point on the source where it was issued from the errors overview, but fails to do so on the second one, because the regular expression it uses to get the line number no longer matches `on line (long-package-name)                19`. And, whether this works or not depends on the length of the package name, and the length of the arguments in the message itself. I presume other editors have similar functionality and likely stumble on the same place.

My question is: how to deal with this? Should I write the messages differently, so that it becomes less sensitive to arbitrary contents of the arguments? Is it possible to somehow change the line wrapping behavior to, e.g., something like?:

```
Package long-package-name Warning:
Warning 'x' for label 'y' on line 17. Some more interesting information to
emphasize the wrapping.

Package long-package-name Warning:
Warning 'lorem' for label 'ipsum' on line 19. Some more interesting
information to emphasize the wrapping.
```

If it is, should I? Should I just not bother and let editors adjust with time? Any other advice in this regard from those with more experience?

A note, I'm not asking how to change the line wrapping column of my terminal, but how a package should handle its messages so that it works well for other people, with different settings and, particularly, with defaults.

Edit: A second data point on editors. I've just tested the MWE on Overleaf, and it also fails to get the line of the second warning.

Comment: This has been the standard error message formatting for more than 20 years…

Comment: @egreg I'm not questioning that... Just, what to do?

Comment: @egreg Besides, I know that it's old. "Waiting for editors to adjust in time" was rethorical... I have personally reported to AUCTeX, past year I think, to match "on line NN" instead of just the old "on input line NN" for the sake of `l3msg`.

Comment: @JosephWright and egreg, In sum, you are telling me: "take this for granted, and write better messages if possible and, if not, resign"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137453/discussion-on-question-by-gusbrs-line-wrapping-of-l3msg-messages).

Comment: Actually the messages of `l3msg` used to look differently, but were changed to look like the ones in LaTeX2e essentially because the team didn't want to break many parsers of editors and scripts.

Comment: @Skillmon I've learned that in the discussion: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61493218#61493218. There's some difference, though, in that `l3msg` is more convenient but can be less predictable of where the line breaks occur. I guess I'll just have to be more careful in writing my warnings. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me add a self-answer, not to leave this one unanswered.

First, it turns out my question was based on a false premise.  This format is not specific to `l3msg` / `expl3`, it is rather the standard format of warning/error messages for LaTeX for a long time.  And `l3msg` actually adopted this format in continuity with what was already in place.  I missed this because in trying out `\PackageWarning` and `\PackageError` and not seeing the continuity lines below the first, I presumed the format was different.  The difference is rather that `\PackageWarning` and `\PackageError` do not automatically wrap the message text, but their intended combined use with some manually set `\MessageBreak`s gives us the same kind of messages.

Still, there is a practical difference, with some implications to the ability of editors to parse the resulting messages.  The difference is that `l3msg` messages auto-wraps the message text, while the standard LaTeX commands for the same purpose require manual line breaking.  This, of course, makes for increased convenience of `l3msg` messages.  However, it also makes it more difficult to predict where the line break will occur if the message contains arguments of potentially variable length.  With `\PackageWarning` and `\PackageError`, in the same circumstances, we might get some overlong message lines, but the break points are deterministic.  So one may have to be more careful in crafting the message to try to avoid the line break in known critical places.

This will, however, depend on given editors' ability to parse these messages and how they do it. For example, if we are interested in ensuring that the editor is able to identify the line number in the source of the message (the problem raised in the OP), and happen to know the editor(s) use a regular expression in the form `"on line NN"`, we could rewrite the message as:

```tex
\msg_new:nnn { long-package-name } { warning-message }
  {
    Warning~\msg_line_context:.~
    Some~more~interesting~information~to~emphasize~the~wrapping~
    about~'#1'~for~label~'#2'.
  }
```

Whether this kind of adjustment works, or is meaningful, depends on the case, on the editor, etc.