# Parse LaTeX errors

Tags: error-writing

I would like to extract latex errors in a given log file (in LaTeX). Unfortunately, I have no idea how to extract them reliably, so for now I just take all lines starting with a `!` , but is is not very robust. For instance if the error is a `\foo` that is not defined, I will only see:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file
produced!
```

but I will not know that it is a `\foo` that is missing.

Similarly, if the error is a LaTeX3 error on multiline like

```
! Package robExt Error: Here are some long
(robExt)                errors that span multiple lines.
```

I will only see the first line `!Package robExt Error: Here are some long`, not very helpful sometimes.

Is there a robust to know when to start, and when to stop?

Comment: in interactive mode you can nore or less go from a line starting `!` to one starting `?` but for example `--file-line-error ` complicates that.

Comment: look at how other editors handle this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2470/which-latex-ides-have-good-warning-error-analysis/7317#7317  also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649548/line-wrapping-of-l3msg-messages

Comment: Why not using tools such as `texlogfilter`?

Comment: @egreg Interesting, but I do not want any Perl dependency (my library might run on windows)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the problem is that I'm not running in interactive mode… So TeX never bother defining an official format for error message? (La)TeX will always amaze me ^^'

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://github.com/reitzig/texlogparser/

Comment: assuming file-line-error is not used the format is as described on the textbook !  to a line number indicator l.123

Comment: Pretty much [compiling - Reducing the console output of LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/reducing-the-console-output-of-latex) . tl;dr no reliable way exists to the best of my knowledge. Just use a bunch of regexes.

Comment: `grep -2 ! foo.log > foo.tex`